# Unable to call Material page route in state class with async delay

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a splash screen for a few seconds then trying to navigate it to the next screen but I am getting this error. Probably because of accessing context in iniState methods but I am also using async so I don't think there's should be any issue.

```
E/flutter ( 6663): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6663): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6663): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
E/flutter ( 6663): #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 6663): #1      Navigator.of 
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2185
```

```
import 'package:awsomeNotes/appUtilities/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:awsomeNotes/views/phoneAuthPage/phoneAuthPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  
  nextPage() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PhoneAuthPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    nextPage();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Dimensions(context);
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          "This is Splash Screen",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: Dimensions.boxHeight * 5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am navigating to the next page but with the error specified.

Comment: This code should run fine. Is your Flutter up-to-date ? (update with `flutter upgrade`). Maybe the issue comes from `PhoneAuthPage()`.

Comment: sry just forgot to delete my question ya its working fine tnx.